# AppCheck fails on ios Simulator

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-app-check

I have appcheck working fine off same codebase on my real ios device,

But on the simulator, I'm seeing:

`await kFirebaseFuncs.httpsCallable('doIt')`
and

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(failed-precondition, The function must be called
from an App Check verified app., {message: The function must be called from an App
Check verified app., code: failed-precondition}, null))
```

Is there something I need to do to make appcheck work on ios simulator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/debug-provider

This is what was needed to fix this

Comment: Unbelievable, could they have implemented this any more clumsy...