# AppCheck failed: The attestation provider AppAttestProvider is not supported on current platform and OS version

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, xcode13, firebase-app-check

I am getting the following error when trying to integrate App Check into my iOS app.

`AppCheck failed: 'The operation couldn’t be completed. The attestation provider AppAttestProvider is not supported on current platform and OS version.'`

And ever since getting this error, when I try to fetch a document from Firestore, I get `Missing or insufficient permissions.` even though all my ready/write security rules are set to `true`.

For reference, I'm using Xcode 13, my projects settings is set to iOS 15.4, and I'm using the [App Attest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/app-attest-provider?hl=en&authuser=0) provider. I am pretty confident I implemented everything correctly, including:

1. Installing FirebaseAppCheck (I used SPM).
2. Adding **App Attest** capability to my app.
3. In my project's `.entitlements` file, set the App Attest environment to `production`.
4. Setting my app check provider factory in my app delegate before calling `FirebaseApp.configure()`.
5. Enabling App Check in my Firebase console.

Comment: What version of Firebase?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Oh sorry, 9.0.0 I believe. I have it set to `Next Major Version`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out it was simply because App Check does not work on the simulator without doing a few extra steps. Read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72313139/appcheck-fails-on-ios-simulator) for the solution.